# Sql query - How to insert values into multiple rows that have same FK

Tags: sql-server

[image]

[image]

Got two tables here. Order might contains multiple order_lines.

What I'm trying to do is to create rows in order_line table by using the trigger I created in order table whenever I insert a new row in order table. The number of rows in order_line is same with item_quantity field in order table.

The problem is the trigger can only insert order_line_id and order_id columns without order_item_type and order_item_quantity because these two value is entered from GUI and the trigger can't insert them at the same time it creates new row.

So I need a sql query that can let me insert multiple values into multiple rows that have same order_id one by one.

Comment: following ACID rules, you should remove item_quantity from your order-table anyway. Rather change your GUI to create those rows for you. The item_quantity can always be retrived via a count on your rows, and should'nt be stored.

Comment: Why do you have a trigger? Why do you not insert order and order line in the same transaction from your application?

Comment: Just new to sql design... Tried to do it via my app but fount that I can't get order_id which is generated by sql...

Comment: But thanks I'm going to go with that idea

Comment: @zhiyuan: In the app you can get the latest order_id created in sql using select @@identity. There are different variations of this that you would need to check which fits your requirement. This assumes order_id fields is autoincremented.